# К чему относиться наречие

Tags: наречия

Я буду долго идти, если я сейчас сюда пришёл и ещё приду. Наречие сейчас относиться к 2 глаголам пришел и приду или только к пришел?

Comment: Странное дело... Вы ведь уже задали такой же точно вопрос 4 часа назад (слово "опять", правда, изничтожилось). В чём смысл повтора?

Comment: А вы не знаете к какому глаголу это наречие относится

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можете относить к чему хотите, смысл определяется из контекста.
Но в большинстве случаев предложения:

```
1 Я буду долго идти, если я сейчас сюда пришёл и ещё приду 
2а Я буду долго идти, если я сюда пришёл и ещё сейчас приду
2б Я буду долго идти, если я сейчас сюда пришёл и сейчас ещё приду
```

отличаются по смыслу

Comment: Я просто не понимаю смысл. Это значит, что человек сейчас придёт или неизвестно когда?

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю. Кто-то кругами ходит, плутает, что ли?

Comment: Смысл может быть разный, скорее всего номер 1: 1. Я сейчас сюда пришел и потом еще приду. 2а. Я сейчас сюда пришел уже один раз и сейчас снова собираюсь прийти. 2б. Уже придя сюда только что, я сейчас собираюсь прийти снова

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Здесь всего ДВА варианта: (1) сейчас относится к обоим предложениям; (2) сейчас относится только к первому предложению. Их надо сравнивать по смыслу.  Непонятно, почему "можете относить к чему хотите"?